# Implementing Dispose() with class derived from System.ComponentModel.Component

Tags: c#, dispose

I made a class that derives from Component:

```
public class MyComponent: System.ComponentModel.Component
{


}
```

I saw that Visual Studio put this code in for me:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    try
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

`MyComponent` has a member that is a `DataSet` and maybe there's some other members that implement `IDisposable`.  What, if anything, do i need to modify with the `Dispose()` method to make sure things are cleaned up properly?  Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
if (disposing && (components != null))
{
     components.Dispose();
}
```

to be:

```
if (disposing && (components != null))
{
    _dataset.Dispose();
    components.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's setting components, but you'd want to dispose _dataset regardless of whether components is null.

Answer (score 0):

Check any disposable member objects and dispose them if they are not null.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this class:

```
public class DisposableComponentWrapper : IComponent
{
    private IDisposable disposable;

    public DisposableComponentWrapper(IDisposable disposable)
    {
        this.disposable = disposable;
    }

    public DisposableComponentWrapper(IDisposable disposable, ISite site)
        : this(disposable)
    {
        Site = site;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (disposable != null)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
        if (Disposed != null)
        {
            Disposed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public ISite Site { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler Disposed;
}
```

and extension method to IContainer:

```
public static void Add(this IContainer container, IDisposable disposableComponent)
{
    var component = (disposableComponent as IComponent);
    if(component == null)
    {
        component = new DisposableComponentWrapper(disposableComponent);
    }
    container.Add(component);
}
```

Which might help those willing to enlist disposable resources to their forms.

Note: I'm not certain of the behaviour for IComponent.Disposed, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icomponent.disposed.aspx) doesn't say much about how it should be called in implementation of this interface, the documentation sounds like talking about client code registering to the event more than when it should be triggered by implementations of this interface.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the disposables in components and add them in the `components` collection. The generated implementation of the dispose pattern will dispose of them correctly.

```
public partial class MyComponent : System.ComponentModel.Component
{
    private readonly System.Data.DataSet _dataSet;

    public MyComponent(System.Data.DataSet dataSet)
    {
        _dataSet = dataSet ?? throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataSet));
        components.Add(new DisposableWrapperComponent(dataSet));
    }
}
```

The `DisposableWrapperComponent` is defined thus:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

public class DisposableWrapperComponent : Component
{
    private bool disposed;

    public IDisposable Disposable { get; }

    public DisposableWrapperComponent(IDisposable disposable)
    {
        Disposable = disposable ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(disposable));
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed) return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            Disposable.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);

        disposed = true;
    }
}
```

<sup>Inspired by the answer by [@smoothdeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17049/smoothdeveloper).</sup>

If you need to be able to reset the data set, encapsulating the lifetime management in a property works quite well.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;

public partial class MyComponent : Component
{
    private const string DataSetComponentName = "dataSet";

    public DataSet DataSet
    {
        get => (DataSet)((DisposableWrapperComponent)components.Components[DataSetComponentName])
                ?.Disposable;
        set
        {
            var lastWrapper = (DisposableWrapperComponent)components.Components[DataSetComponentName];
            if (lastWrapper != null)
            {
                components.Remove(lastWrapper);
                lastWrapper.Dispose();
            }

            if (value != null)
            {
                components.Add(new DisposableWrapperComponent(value), DataSetComponentName);
            }
        }
    }

    public MyComponent(DataSet dataSet)
    {
        DataSet = dataSet ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataSet));
    }
}
```

I used this when implementing a Windows Service that creates a disposable object in `OnStart` and disposes of it in `OnStop`.